# c++: how to put relevant bits from uint32 into uint8?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, mask, bit

I have a uint32 that I've flagged some bits on:

```
uint32 i = 0;
i |= (1 << 0);
i |= (1 << 5); 
i |= (1 << 13);
i |= (1 << 19);
...
```

I want to convert it to a uint8 (by getting the state of its first 8 bits and disregarding the rest). Obviously I could do this:

```
uint8 j = 0;
for (int q = 0; q < 8; q++)
{
    if (i & (1 << q))
    {
        j |= (1 << q);
    }
}
```

But is there a fancy bitwise operation I can use to transfer the bits over in one fell swoop, without a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the same result by simply assigning the uint32 value to uint8.

```
int main()
{
  unsigned int i = 0x00000888;
  unsigned char j = i;
  cout<<hex<<i<<endl;
  cout<<hex<<+j<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

output:
888
88

Comment: Wow I was really overthinking it...a straight conversion to unsigned char seems to work!

Answer (score 3):

Why not just mask those last 8 bits instead of running a loop over to see if individual bits are set?

```
const unsigned char bitMask = 0xFF;
j = (i & bitMask);
```

Note that C++ 14 though allows you to define binary literals right away

```
const unsigned char bitMask = 0b1111'1111;
```

The above is all you need. Just in case, if you need to get the subsequent byte positions, use the same mask `0xFF` and make sure to right shift back the result to get the desired byte value.

Comment: Or you could sinply or it together like `j |= i` (given that `j` is set to `0`) although i am not sure if that throws a warning since it casts to a smaller type but the above does too.

Comment: @Yastanub: Yes, fair point. I don't think a warning would be thrown.

Comment: you don't event need to bit mask since you are converting to a smaller type. Although for good style you should be using proper static_cast.